# How can I create a WordPress Plugin with custom CSS?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

I want to create a WordPress Plugin where I want to add some css, and upon activation, those css will be in effect and be viewing in the website. Upon deactivation, the css will also be out of effect.

Any how I can do that? Or any documentation I can take help from?

Comment: You should create a plugin that would simple [register/enqueue](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) the CSS file(s). One simple PHP file for style enqueuing alongside with your CSS file(s) should be enough for this use case. If you don't know how, you should really [start here](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/intro/).

Answer (score 0):

You can follow Plugin Handbook for creating a plugin https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/.

create a CSS file in plugin directory then upon plugin activation hook you can enqueue the CSS file using action 'wp_enqueue_style'.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your main file to load your css file:

```
function add_my_css() {
    $plugin_url = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style',  $plugin_url . "/css/plugin-style.css");
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_css' );
```

Then create your plugin-style.css file and write your css.

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried using this code:

function add_my_css() {
    $plugin_url = plugin_url( __FILE__ );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style',  $plugin_url . "/css/plugin-style.css");
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_css' );

But all CSS is not being loaded. Only some are being shown in the website :'(
Can you please help?

Comment: If you some of your css is loaded it means it works and it is possible that the problem come from your css file. Can you share it? Or what you can do is simply comment each line of your css and see which one is causing the problem